# SQL Injection Attack on Select Statement

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to accomplish a SQL injection using Tamper Data add-on on Firefox. I was provided a web site prepared for this purpose and what I need to do is to fill the username and password fields with appropriate strings to be logged in.

First of all, I double checked that "magic quotes gpc" is Off. After that, I write the following line both to the user name and password;

```
test' or '1=1
```

But still, I cannot log-in to the system. Any idea why is that happening?

Here is the php code for sql;

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id, username, user_password, user_active, user_level, user_login_tries,
user_last_login_try FROM " . USERS_TABLE . " WHERE username = '" . $username . "'";
```

Comment: And what queries you're test? do you find some data into the system? Remember to achieve this attack the idea behind it's getting data from  the database through the application

Comment: Any idea why *What* is happening? Your inability to login to the site? Ability to change the database? No matter what, more information will be needed to 'answer' your question. However, check your SQL Syntax and command structure and ensure you are attempting valid SQL for the injection.

Comment: Thank you, I know that I will need to get data from the database but I'm kinda stuck at the first step of the project, which is just to log-in to the system :)

Comment: Based on the query you posted, you can use: `' OR 1 OR '` which will work. Also `' OR 1 --` will work (this one comments out the closing quotes)

Comment: For test' OR 1 OR' I still get invalid user error, and for the test' OR 1 -- I get syntax error saying username = 'test' or 1 --'

Comment: @ÖzgenErbakan update the question with the SQL from the PHP code. Does the username really have spaces around it like in your comment? `username = ' " . $username . " ' "`

Comment: I updated it, and you are right there shouldn't be any spaces between ' and " but it exists between " and dots.

Comment: `' OR 1 OR '` should be working unless magic quotes or any other code is interfering with `$username`. Is `$username` just `$username=$_POST['username']`? If you can, echo out the whole of `$sql` after an attempt, to see what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 3):

Tricky to answer that without doing your homework for you.

Try writing down the query that you imagine the site is executing when you submit, with a normal username, and then also write down the query with your username.

Is the syntax still valid?

A "SQL injected" command must (usually) still be valid SQL.

Comment: I already know there there is a person registered for the site with then name "ted" and password "ted" also. So, when I try to inject my code like ted' or '1=1 then it works, but when I try it like ted' and '1=1 then it does not. This seems weird to me and I really have no clue why it is happening.

Comment: My point is that the final syntax after your hacky username **must** be valid SQL, not just anything after a `'`

Comment: @ÖzgenErbakan: Visualize the query AFTER you've injected it, with your `'1` version.

Comment: When I type the username as test' or '1=1', I get a syntax error saying username = 'test' or '1=1''. So I suppose, if I inject test' or '1=1 then the final syntax becomes valid which I can also understand from not getting a syntax error but just a warning of an invalid user name.

Comment: @ÖzgenErbakan see my comment on the question for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the SQL is written. If you know that, then post it. If you don't, then it is your job to keep trying different attack methods, making different assumptions about the database and SQL query, until you do get in.

I'd like to have a shot at it as well. What's the address?

**EDIT:**
Now that the SQL has been posted, I suggest to the OP to add a LIMIT clause to the attack. Also, move the second quote `'` character to a better place (you still need to consider the end quote of the SQL statement).

Comment: $sql = "SELECT user_id, username, user_password, user_active, user_level, user_login_tries, user_last_login_try
                        FROM " . USERS_TABLE . "
                        WHERE username = ' " . $username . " ' ";

This is the php code. And the address of the site is www.sqllabmysqlphpbb.com

Comment: @dotancohen, I wouldn't advise testing SQLi's on sites that people post on SO. Although OP sounds genuine, anyone can post any site and so you could end up in hot water unless the site explicitly invites SQLi attempts from the public and gives permission.